QuarkUS Rest Client - Send Body version 3.10.2
The following code used to work before I upgraded my QuarkUS version to 3.10.2
After upgrading I am getting error "can only have a single body parameter: token"
import io.quarkus.rest.client.reactive.NotBody;
import io.quarkus.vertx.web.Body;
import jakarta.ws.rs.GET;
import jakarta.ws.rs.HeaderParam;
import jakarta.ws.rs.Path;
import jakarta.ws.rs.PathParam;

import org.eclipse.microprofile.rest.client.annotation.ClientHeaderParam;
import org.eclipse.microprofile.rest.client.annotation.RegisterClientHeaders;
import org.eclipse.microprofile.rest.client.inject.RegisterRestClient;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;


@RegisterRestClient(configKey = "aa-api")
@RegisterClientHeaders(RequestUUIDHeaderFactory.class)
public interface HttpProductService {
    @GET
    @Path("/aa/productNames")
    @ClientHeaderParam(name = "Authorization", value = "Bearer {token}")
    List<PDto> getProductNames(@PathParam("userId") String uid,
                                     @NotBody String token,
                                     Set<String> pc);

I tied various combinations, it didn't work.

You are missing a {userId} in your path

Do you have a sample application I can check?
